# Animation with View  iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I new in iOS development. Can somebody help me? 
I have view:

.h file:

```
  UIView *secondView;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [secondView setFrame: CGRectMake(100,60,30,30)];
 [self.view addSubview:secondView];

}
```

How to make that by pressing the button secondView is turned on full screen with animation?

Comment: Also might be worth actually trying to write some code and posting your progress, but seems as there are lot's of examples of animation out there I'm going to guess you haven't bothered at all

Comment: I don't know how works with animation!!! that's why I wrote here!

Comment: And how I can up rate???

Comment: @user1496571_BrainOverflow You see a checkmark beside every answer to your question? Go click on it to accept the answer that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question: 
In viewDidLoad method need to add as subview second view with frame

```
[secondView setFrame: CGRectMake(10,20,90,90)];
```

And in touchesBegan method need to add:

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];     

 [secondView setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

That's all. Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 1):

On tap you can change button frame dynamically with zoom out animation.:)
you can take idea by this code:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        zoomerView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(zoomerView.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting the center and then doing nothing with it?

Comment: Thanks for some information!!!

Answer (score -1):

First of all from what I can interpret , there is a `UIScrollView` holding various images . When   you click on an image it enlarges. Actually this can be done by animation or without it also.
For animation use the zoom out method . Without it just display a `UIImageView` of the same image enlarged, work with it and then save it... easier said than done.

Comment: I need not do it with pictures! I need do it with View's(((